# Code mp3 audio files into image format

Tags: language-agnostic, image-processing, mp3

Once I read that it is possible to code mp3 files into an image format (let's say .png), and to decode the image file into the mp3 back again. However, I lost that link, and now I can't find good info about this.

Three questions for you folks:
Is this really possible? Does it make sense? Would it decrease considerably the mp3 file size?

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://www.labnol.org/internet/pictures/upload-mp3-music-files-flickr-hosting/3503/)? Note that it doesn't actually code the MP3 files into an image format, it simply adds both files into a single binary. It's not a conversion, and it doesn't require any decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is this really possible?*

Yes - you can use anything as a source for the colours in an image.

*Does it make sense?*

Not really - the image wouldn't look good, and the music wouldn't be easily playable. The only likely reason for doing this is [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography), i.e. hiding the mp3 inside an image of something else so that it's not easily detected.

*Would it decrease considerably the mp3 file size?*

No, the file size would almost certainly be larger than the original (and *much* larger in the steganography case).